# Duplicates and issues with favorites in the dock

Tags: dock, 21.10

Since upgrading to 21.10, I've been having two issues in the dock.

1. Sometimes, the system won't let me add certain apps to favorites. The option does not appear when right clicking the icon. This seems to be random, though. Meaning, in another session, I might be able to do it.
2. Some apps in favorites duplicate in the dock when I open them. The new icon appear below favorites.

Have any of you experienced this?

Comment: Yes, but it is due to specific applications and specific reasons. Provide examples of where issues appear.

Comment: Google chrome, when like --ignore-certificate-errors is added, and launched via launcher it works, when added to favorites and launched via favorites it doesn't work...  Still works when closed and launched via apps

Comment: Hm, looks like it has something to do with restarting app and gnome...